# Proving $m^*(A\cap B)+m^*(A\cup B)\le m^*(A)+m^*(B)$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

> Let $A,B\subset\mathbb R$. Then $m^*(A\cap B)+m^*(A\cup B)\le m^*(A)+m^*(B)$

It holds that $m^*(A\cup B)\le m^*(A)+m^*(B)$ for any $A,B$

hence $A\cap B$ must be the empty set.

how to prove that $(A\cap B)$ is the empty set?

I thought in using complements but I arrive to $m^*((A^c\cup B^c)^c)$

though I don't see how  would that help.

I also   <s>know</s> think both sets are Lebesgue measure

Someone please help me

Comment: $m^*(A\cap B)$ isn't a set, but rather an element of $[0,+\infty]$. Are you trying to show $A \cap B = \varnothing$? If so, that wouldn't necessarily be true nor is it necessary.

Comment: @GaryMoon  Yes, that would be equal to $0$

Comment: Gotcha. In general, it won't be $0$.

Comment: Are you sure that both sets are measurable? If they are then you can actually prove equality using measures and not outer measures (which agree on measurable sets.)

Comment: @K.Power well I supposed that they are measurable, the proposition did not mention that though

Comment: Then that is a wrong assumption, because you can prove this statement without assuming measurability.

Comment: @K.Power :( well I am starting with this.. I have lot of mistakes

Comment: I am not attacking you, but just letting you know that in general it is incorrect to add your own additional assumptions to a proposition in order to make the proof easier, because then you are proving a weaker proposition than what was asked for.

Comment: @K.Power thank you I appreciate your comment. I did not take your comment as 'attacking me'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not true in general that $m^*(A \cap B)=0$. Consider $A=[0,1]$ and $B=[-1,1]$.

Edit: Since $A$ and $B$ are Lebesgue measurable, we have
$$m^*(A) = m^*(A\setminus B) + m^*(A \cap B)$$
and
$$m^*(B) = m^*(B \setminus A) + m^*(A\cap B).$$
So,
$$m^*(A) + m^*(B) = m^*(A\setminus B) + m^*(A \cap B) +  m^*(B \setminus A) + m^*(A\cap B) = m^*(A\cup B) + m^*(A \cap B).$$
The final equality holds as $A\setminus B \cup B\setminus A \cup (A\cap B) = A \cup B$.

Edit 2: I took the OP to indicate that $A$ and $B$ are Lebesgue measurable. This proof WON'T work without that assumption.

Edit 3: Now we need to try to extend this to arbitrary $A,B \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$. To do so, we need a definition of Lebesgue outer measure:
$$m^*(E) = \inf\bigg\{ \sum_i \ell(I_i) : I_i \text{ open intervals and } \bigcup_i I_i \supset E \bigg\},$$
where $\ell$ denotes length. Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be arbitrary. Then, by definition, there exists $I = \cup_i I_i$ and $J = \cup_j J_j$, unions of open intervals with $I \supset A$ and $J \supset B$, so that $m^*(A)\geq m^*(I) - \varepsilon$ and $m^*(B) \geq m^*(J) - \varepsilon$. Then, noting that $I$ and $J$ are (Lebesgue) measurable, we have
$$m^*(A) + m^*(B) \geq m^*(I) + m^*(J) - 2\varepsilon = m^*(I\cap J) + m^*(I \cup J) - 2\varepsilon \geq m^*(A \cap B) + m^*(A \cup B) - 2\varepsilon.$$
Sending $\varepsilon \downarrow 0$ will complete the proof.

Edit 4: Based on a comment, I'm going to offer a bit of extra detail as to why $m^*(A\cap B) + m^*(A \cup B) = m^*(A) + m^*(B)$ when $A$ and $B$ are (Lebesgue) measurable sets. Utilizing the Caratheodory condition on $A$ and $B$ we arrived at
$$m^*(A) + m^*(B) = m^*(A\setminus B) + m^*(A \cap B) +  m^*(B \setminus A) + m^*(A\cap B).$$
We want to get $m^*(A \cap B) + m^*(A \cup B)$ out of this expression, so let's look at the terms $m^*(A\setminus B) + m^*(B \setminus A) + m^*(A\cap B)$. Consider the following union:
$$A\setminus B \cup B\setminus A \cup A\cap B = A \cup B.$$
Notice that the three sets on the LHS are all mutually disjoint. This implies
$$m^*(A \cup B) = m^*(A\setminus B \cup B\setminus A \cup A\cap B) = m^*(A\setminus B) + m^*(B \setminus A) + m^*(A\cap B).$$
It then follows that
$$m^*(A\setminus B) + m^*(A \cap B) +  m^*(B \setminus A) + m^*(A\cap B) = m^*(A \cup B) + m^*(A \cap B).$$
Therefore, we conclude that, for $A$ and $B$ measurable,
$$m^*(A) + m^*(B) = m^*(A \cup B) + m^*(A \cap B).$$

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91375/discussion-on-answer-by-gary-moon-how-to-prove-that-ma-cap-b0).